# multiple select query in single laravel query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to write the laravel query qhich want to has multiple select query in single query

```
select name,owner from project where owner in (select a.user_name from users a left join users b on a.manager=b.firstname where a.user_name='sridhar.ps' or a.manager like '%sridhar p%' or b.manager like '%sridhar p%') and customer_code='OTH_0071'
```

The above query list the outpu what I want exactly.I want to change the query in laravel

Answer (score 1):

with the help of whereRaw you can do that like this

```
DB::table('project')->where('customer_code','OTH_0071')->whereRaw("owner in (select a.user_name from users a left join users b on a.manager=b.firstname where a.user_name='sridhar.ps' or a.manager like '%sridhar p%' or b.manager like '%sridhar p%')")->select('name','owner')->get();
```

for using variable

```
DB::table('project')->where('customer_code','OTH_0071')->whereRaw("owner in (select a.user_name from users a left join users b on a.manager=b.firstname where a.user_name='sridhar.ps' or a.manager like '%".$manager."%' or b.manager like '%sridhar p%')")->select('name','owner')->get();
```

for more info vist [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) $manager

hope it will help you!

Comment: in raw query I want to use variable

Comment: you can just concatenate it

Comment: $project_code=DB::table('project')->where('customer_code',$customer_name)->whereRaw("owner in (select a.user_name from users a left join users b on a.manager=b.firstname where a.user_name=".$user_name." or a.manager =".$first_name." or b.manager =".$first_name.")")->pluck('name','code')->all();             i have tried.but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156524/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-user3386779).

Answer (score 1):

I might first rewrite your query using a series of joins:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    p.owner
FROM project p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.user_name
    FROM users a
    LEFT JOIN users b
        ON a.manager = b.firstname
    WHERE
        a.user_name = 'sridhar.ps'   OR
        a.manager LIKE '%sridhar p%' OR
        b.manager LIKE '%sridhar p%'
) t
    ON p.owner = t.user_name
WHERE
    p.customer_code = 'OTH_0071';
```

Then build the Laravel query using a raw subquery to represent the table aliased as `t` above:

```
$subquery  = "(SELECT a.user_name FROM users a LEFT JOIN users b ";
$subquery .= "ON a.manager = b.firstname ";
$subquery .= "WHERE a.user_name = 'sridhar.ps' OR a.manager LIKE '%sridhar p%' ";
$subquery .= "OR b.manager LIKE '%sridhar p%') AS t";
DB:table('project)
    ->select('name', 'owner')
    ->join(DB::raw($subquery), 'p.owner', '=', 't.user_name')
    ->where('customer_code','OTH_0071')
    ->get();
```

This join approach might be more performant than what you currently have.  In any case, you can test this answer, compare it against the answer by @Gaurav, and then use whichever works the best.

Comment: @user3386779 Sorry I had omitted that.  I updated my answer.  Just make the call to `where` as you normally would; you don't need a raw query for this.

Comment: I have tried to select name and code but not working

Comment: _but not working_ ... can you be more precise than this?  What is the error message?  Can you try running my raw MySQL query as well?